# Since AB = I = BA does this mean AB = BA?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that $AB = I = BA$ where afaik, $A^{-1} = B$ and $B^{-1} = A$

So does this also mean that $AB = BA$?

I know by itself, $AB = BA$ is not necessarily the same as matrix multiplication isn't commutative, but since they both equal the identity matrix does that mean they're equal?

I'm trying to use this idea in a problem, but not sure if it's valid...

Given

- $DET(A)<= 0$
- $A^2 = I$
- $AB^3=I$
- $AB = B^3A$
- $ACA=BC$

Find $DET(A)$

If $AB^3=I$ then $B^3A = I$ and $AB=I$ as $AB = B^3A$.

If $AB=I$ and $A^2=I$ then $A=B$ as $A^2 = AB$

Then $DET(A) = DET(B)$

Comment: If two things are equal to a third one, they are equal to each other.

Comment: If $AB=I=BA$, then of course $AB=BA$. However, $AB^3=I$ does not imply that $B^3A=I$. In fact, $AB=B^3A$ implies that $$I=AB^3=B^3AB^2=B^6AB=B^9A\;.$$

Comment: you might be confusing 'if $x\in A, y\in A \implies x=y$', .. you might not :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, this is just the transitive property at work. Notating that three things are equal like $AB=I=BA$ is the same as giving all the pairwise equalities, but with less ink. Writing out $AB=I$ , $BA=I$, and $AB=BA$ is a bit cumbersome.

**Edit**

The matrix $B$ is in fact $A^{-1}$. This is due to the existence of $A^{-1}$ not being automatic, so instead we define the matrix $B$ to be $A^{-1}$ if it exists. Also notice that this definition requires $B$ to be a left- and right-inverse of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any of that. Use the transitive property of equality.

If $X=Y=Z$, with $X,Y,Z$ matrices, then $X=Z$.

Answer (score 0):

It will be clear if you state the condition for that:

For square matrices A and B if AB = I then AB = I = BA. In particular AB = BA.